# How do I instantiate an object with fields from the parent class?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I am trying to get an understanding of object oriented programming in Java and I have this problem.

Say for example, I have a a parent class like this:

```
public class Shape {
    private int location;
    private Color color;
    // methods such as getLocation() and getColor()

    public Shape(int initialLocation, Color initialColor) {
        location = initialLocation;
        color = initialColor;
    }


}
```

How do I make my child class so that I can construct, say, a rectangle with an initial location and an initial color in a main method? Do I create a constructor in the Rectangle class? I can't because location and color are private fields. Do I create accessor methods for location and color and just set the location and color after instantiation? I guess, but is there a way to do this without accessors?

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public Rectangle(int initialLocation, Color initialColor) {
        super(initialLocation, initialColor);
    }

}
```

I just can't wrap my head around this fundamental concept. Any help?

Comment: You can reuse your parent class' constructor with a `super(...)` call. Or use setters.

Comment: Why on earth would a `Rectangle` extend a `Vehicle`?

Comment: @RohitJain Vehicle? Where?

Comment: @Dukeling. Hm. Question is edited now.

Comment: Sorry about that haha, looking at multiple examples making my head spin.

Comment: @GigaTocka. haha :) Welcome to the Head Spinning world :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reuse constructors

```
public class Shape {
    private int location;
    private Color color;

    public Shape(int location, Color color) {
        this.location = location;
        this.color = color;
    }
    // methods such as getLocation() and getColor()
}
```

and

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public Rectangle(int location, Color color /*, more */) { 
        super(location, color);
        // more
    }
}
```

This [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) explains its use.

Comment: @Giga Do you still have a question?

Comment: Yes, if I have a longer inheritance hierarchy. For example, Shape -> MovingShape -> Rectangle. I have to create a constructor for the MovingShape class in the same fashion. Correct?

Comment: @Giga Yes you do. Note that if your parent has a constructor, your child must explicitly invoke it with a `super()` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend the variables you may change their modifiers to `protected`, so it can be inherited, otherwise `private` is just like they didn't exist for the child class.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can define the instance variables as `protected`, however, this goes against the Object Oriented principle of encapsulation. I would use the getters and setters for each instance variable of the class Shape. Also, if you create a Constructor within Shape you could call the super constructor in Rectangle to set the location and colour in Rectangle.

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public Rectangle(int location, Color color) { 
        super(location, color);
    }
}
```

as long as you have the following constructor in Shape:

```
public class Shape {
    // location and color define.

    public Shape(int location, Color color) {
        this.location = location;
        this.color = color;
    }
    // getters and setters which are public for location and color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Private members in a base class that are only accessed by subclasses are pointless!
If you want to read them, you'll need at least a public or protected getter.
If you want to write them, you'll need at least a public or protected setter and/or a constructor that initializes them.